# What are possible causes of system crash / freeze while using cmpxchg() <asm/cmpxchg.h> on 32 bit Ububtu 12.4.2?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver

I've simple called cmpxchg() from cmpxchg.h ,code works on 64 bit version and Virtual Machine for both version.System freezes and can't be recovered even after reboot..

Comment: It's an unprivileged feature, so the causes are unlimited.  You should debug this the same way you would any other system crash/freeze.  Consider the crash dump features of modern kernels, `Alt-SysRq-<x>`, etc.

Comment: There is some other problem with your code. Which you have kept a secret.